# How to update records in an Access subform based on a query?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an access form which uses a query looking into the SQL database (using connection string via ODBC). When I load the form, I can only view the data in each record.  How can I make my form allow changing the values of the existing record fields, or adding new records?

Among the form properties, the "Allow Additions", "Allow Deletions", "Allow Edits", and "Allow Filters" are all set to "yes".  I have tried all the possibles values for "Data Entry" and "Record Lock" but no luck.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please add more details.

Comment: Linked SQL Server tables need to have a primary key, to be updateable in Access. Try if the table is updateable in Access when opened directly without the form. If your Form uses an Access query, check if the query is updateable without the form. - If you need further help, amend the results from those checks and more details on table/query structure to the question.